# How to convert a zip file into an octet stream

Tags: java, soap, zip, webservices-client

I am working on SOAP web services. I have been given a third party WSDL URL for which I need to generate client code. I need to pass a zip file which contains a bundle of XML, for which the passing parameter should be type octet stream. I don't know how to pass an argument as an octet stream. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A SOAP Web-service needs to return the result in a format defined by SOAP - basically in XML. Octet streams are a different mechanism of file/data transfer, so that's not what you need.

What you need to use is "[SOAP with Attachments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments)" or "[MTOM (Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism)", where you ZIP file will be attached to the SOAP message in some way. If you're using Java with Axis 2, [This article in the Axis documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html) describes what you what you need to do.

Remember that your webservice clients will also need to understand MTOM or SwA. So pick the approach that is easily supported by your clients.

Comment: ...I m using elipse soapui . I cant find any details in wsdl-URL regarding MTOM or SWA.How to find whether webservices client will support MTOM or SWA.

Comment: Your WSDL won't contain any references to MTOM or SOAP with Attachments unless you add that support to your web service. To figure out what your web-service clients support, you need to talk to the people building those clients.